# Select Query Doesn't Show All Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a combobox on a subform (*ProgramSubform*) in Access that's supposed to list report years for a project from a table (*Program*). Most projects have more than one report year, but the combobox always brings only 2014.

For example, the dropdown for project 5278 should be:

```
2012
2013
2014
```

Instead, it's only

`2014`

This is the select query that I'm using. It was working properly before, but I don't know when it stopped working; no changes were made to the tables or subform.

```
SELECT Program.ReportYear
FROM Program
WHERE (((Program.ProjNo)='ProgramSubform.ProjNo'));
```

Any idea why it might have stopped working, or how to fix it?

Comment: please show the table content, and what are you expect. its not clear what was your result and what you want to have as result.

Comment: I added some information to the question. Does this clarify?

Comment: What is *ProgramSubform.ProjNo*?  Are you dealing with a form which contains a subform control named *ProgramSubform* and that subform includes a control named *ProjNo*?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `WHERE` clause asks Access to limit the rows returned by the query to those whose *ProjNo* values match the text string *'ProgramSubform.ProjNo'*

```
WHERE (((Program.ProjNo)='ProgramSubform.ProjNo'))
```

But *ProgramSubform.ProjNo* is actually a data control on a subform.  So don't include quotes around its name.

You can use a reference to the control via the parent form in the `Forms` collection:

```
WHERE Program.ProjNo= Forms![Parent Form]!ProgramSubform!ProjNo
```

If you're building the `SELECT` statement with VBA code in the form, you can include the control's value instead of its name:

```
"WHERE Program.ProjNo=" & Me!ProgramSubform!ProjNo.Value
"WHERE Program.ProjNo='" & Me!ProgramSubform!ProjNo.Value & "'"
```

Use the first version for a numeric field or the second for text.

Notes:

1. I assumed *ProgramSubform* is the name of the subform *control*.  It could also be the name of the form contained in that subform control.  But those names can be different.  So make sure you used the subform *control* name.
2. This query is used as the Row Source for a combo box on the subform.  You want to update the values displayed in the combo whenever `ProjNo.Value` changes.  You can accomplish that by calling the combo's `Requery` method from the After Update event of `ProjNo`.

Comment: This kind of works, except it only brings the years for the first project for all the reports. So say I open it to ProjNo 5278, it gives me `2012, 2013, 2014`. When I switch to another project, it still shows me those report years even though this report has, say, 2013, 2014`.

Comment: I used this answer here to refresh it, and it works perfectly now. Thank you very much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471679/refresh-requery-combobox-problems

Comment: Ack!  I actually meant `Requery`; `Refresh` was a mistake.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the brackets, you have three before Program.ProjNo on WHERE clause, but you only need two brackets (in this case) you should use:

```
SELECT Program.ReportYear
FROM Program
WHERE ((Program.ProjNo='ProgramSubform.ProjNo'));
```

anyway you will prefer:

```
SELECT Program.ReportYear
FROM Program
WHERE Program.ProjNo='ProgramSubform.ProjNo';
```